# Mongo DB, mongod.lock

Tags: mongodb, initialization, runtime, nosql

Folks, I have a question about `MongoDB`, is the following, `MongoDB` installed in Windows Service, for whenever I start the computer, start the service together, just that .. is not working .. checking the error logs says the `mongod.lock` already exists, and then to the service and starts, stops and starts .. looks like all the time .. until I disable and delete the file, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically end up with the mongodb.lock if you don't shutdown mongodb properly. In this case maybe you need to repair the database before mongo can successfully start. To avoid this, make sure mongodb gets properly shut down.

Comment: My command: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongo\bin\mongod" --service --rest --master --logpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\MongoLog.txt" --dbpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data", what i need to increase ?

Comment: sorry i don't understand. increase?

Comment: as i told you, make sure to properly shut down mongodb. the command to start mongo is good, that's not the problem. i don't use windows, but i'd assume if you just turn off windows without stopping mongodb first, you end up with mongodb.lock. so run this command, once you're done, kill the process (control C or however you do that in windows), and you won't be getting this file.